# CenOS shows incorrect week number

Tags: php, centos, week-number

I'm using php date('W'); function to get a number of the week of this year.

```
date('W')  says "40" (that's correct).
```

The problem is, that my Linux machine, CentOS has a correct date, but shows incorrect week number.

```
date +"%W" says "39"
```

Does anyone know why it works this way and how could I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found the answer:

I need to use it like this:
    date +%V

%V   ISO week number, with Monday as first day of week (01..53)

%W   week number of year, with Monday as first day of week (00..53)

Answer (score 0):

```
date('W');
```

The code above gives the ISO-8601 week number (don't know what Linux shows by default). If you want the correct year there as well, use

```
date('W o');
```

instead of (W Y), because the o gives the right year with the W-week.